# How to replace a column value for the matching records within a table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which has some matching values of employees i.e. an employee could be in multiple departments.
I wanted to identify those records on the basis of their "name" and "dob". if it is same then replace the "id" as an increment of the decimal.
In below example: Mike is in 2 departments (IT, Finance) so I want his IT dept id (as an increment of the decimal) in the final outcome. Base id can identified on the basis department IT.

Please let me know how can I do this?

[image]

Comment: How do we know that `12` is the base `id` value for `john`, and not `89`?  In general, this might not be clear or possible.

Comment: On the basis of Department (IT)

Comment: On the basis of department (IT)? What does that mean? What if `ken` is in departments Finance and HR, and therefore none of the rows is in IT? Tim's question makes perfect sense; your answers doesn't. And please note that this question has nothing to do with programming - it's about the business problem itself (nothing to do with computers or databases at this stage).

Comment: I only want to replace the id of a employee which is in IT despartment

Comment: "replace the "id" as an increment of the decimal."  What is this supposed to mean?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take the min id and the row number divided by 10:

```
SELECT
  MIN(id) OVER(PARTITION BY name, dob) + ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name, dob ORDER BY id)-1)/10 as id,
  name,
  dob,
  department
FROM
  emp
```

I chose the min id for the employee as the base id. If you have a different strategy, like you want IT dept id to form the base value, instead of MIN(id) consider something like `FIRST_VALUE(id) OVER(PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY case when department = 'it' then 0 else 1 end)`

I agree with tim though; there seems a good deal of your question thatvis unclear poorly specified or not completely thought through. What if an emp is in 10 departments and an id conflict occurs? Generally we don't care about what an id number is so we don't change it or try to fill up gaps etc

Comment: Thanks Caius, Can I do this by using the self join on the table itself?